# How to correctly put line on top of seaborn boxplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I have a seaborn boxplot that I want to overlay with a matplotlib (or similar) line plot.  After I plot the boxplot, the line plot will not align with the data as if the boxplot has changed the image scale and relabeled the ticks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drl0H.png

Here are the y-values for the line:

[0.18204693 0.19666831 0.21215943 0.22852364 0.24575633 0.26384408
 0.28276401 0.30248319 0.32295832 0.34413563 0.365951   0.38833047
 0.41119098 0.43444143 0.45798398 0.48171566 0.50553011 0.52931951
 0.55297644 0.5763959  0.5994771  0.62212514 0.6442525  0.66578024
 0.68663888 0.70676909 0.72612194 0.74465897 0.76235198 0.77918256
 0.79514148 0.81022792 0.82444864 0.83781702 0.85035218 0.86207798
 0.87302219 0.88321561 0.89269132 0.90148395 0.90962905 0.91716262
 0.92412056 0.93053833 0.93645062 0.9418911  0.94689224 0.95148513
 0.95569939 0.95956314]

As you can see, that's not what is being displayed.

If I just plot the line without plotting the boxplot first, it looks correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Ghq.png

```
    bp = sns.boxplot(ax=self.ax[0], x="dose", y="resp", color='white', width=0.1, data=self.flattened)
    bp.plot(x, y, '--', color='black')
```